# What would be the best solution to import map on 1.8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Will all know that 1.8 is released and I'm sure lots of us are wondering, what will happen with our maps on this update. With the rivers, tunnels, new biomes, etc... old chunck might broke with the new ones making the map kinda odds.

So what could be the best solution to move to 1.8 without having the reset the map and lose all structures that players have made.

I was thinking to make a region from the whole village and save it with World Edit but I dunno if it's a good idea..

What will you guys do in my place ?

Comment: Hello, Warface -- Unfortunately, since 1.8 is currently not out, any answer would be purely speculative. Once 1.8 has been released, I would be happy to reopen this question for discussion.

Comment: @Warface — Yes, many people may have ideas about how they'll go about it, but as RD points out, it's only speculation, based on the assumption that the 1.7 -> 1.8 upgrade will work like all the previous upgrades. While that's probably a *safe* assumption, it's a lousy answer. You're better off looking at how previous upgrades have worked; the answers will be the same as they would have been for this question, only won't midlead if the 1.8 upgrade turns out to require something unforeseen.

Comment: Since 1.8 has now been pre-released, I have reopened this question.

Comment: World Editing the structures would be the best bet

Comment: Yeah because I made a map with the pre-release 1.8 then reinstalled 1.7.3 to load it and the new chunks were cut off to make the new ones. And the biomes was messed up too. Water was turning into ice in a normal biome :S Also it seems that Seed name or number are not generated to same from 1.7.3 to 1.8... it give another map even if it's the same seed. Weird but it's a pre-released heh!

Comment: What do you mean by _map_? The Singuplayer worlds stay the same, though chunks that haven't ever been loaded generate 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately since the level generation algorithm has changed, using the same seed as before will generate a completely different map in its place.  There are new biomes, their sizes are different, and the land features are different too.  Since my friend and I have structures we would like to save, we're faced with the same problem you are.

It is nearly impossible to get a world that will match your existing one, and if your structures are like ours, it depends heavily on the land it was built on.  Maybe you can paste in a whole island at once or something, but even then the biomes won't match (if you care about appropriate weather in the area you built it).

This is admittedly an opinion here, but my advice would be to start fresh; turn a new page.  The Adventure Update is for exploring!  Go have fun with the new features, and save your maps elsewhere for nostalgia. The update supports old maps, so you can always go back to see them and build upon them.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [MCEdit](http://davidvierra.com/mcedit.html) to export your buildings, re-create the map using the same seed, then import your buildings back in to the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NBTedit and change the map features to 0 and in NEW CHUNKS all the new feature will start appearing. Or you could copy all the stuff you have, and inventory start a new world and just use mcedit to copy paste your stuff.